# Count multiple columns grouped by date

Tags: mysql

My current query looks like this

```
SELECT `task`, COUNT(*) as sum 
FROM tasks 
where `datetask` between ? and ? 
  AND `taskstatus` = ?  
GROUP BY DATE(`datetask`) 
ORDER BY `datetask` ASC
```

Parameter status is currently 1. What If I wanted to make multiple status count up? Like 3-4 per date

```
"query": [
      {
        "datetask": "2015-11-04 00:00:00",
        "status1": "1"
      },
      {
        "datetask": "2015-11-05 00:00:00",
        "status1": "1"
      }
    ]
```

What I want to accomplish

```
DATE         | Status 1  | Status 2 | Status 3 
---------------------------------------------
2015-11-04   | 3         | 3        | 3
2015-11-05   | 2         | 3        |
2015-11-06   | 5         | 3        | 3
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `SELECT DATE(datetask)` instead of `SELECT task`?

Comment: I want it to be date - count[status =1]  - count[status =2]  - count[status =3] for example

Comment: Can you show us some sample output data of what you want?

Comment: Added example in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some comment on the existing query:

- Every expression that is not in the `GROUP BY` list should not appear in the `SELECT` list, unless it is inside an aggregate function (`SUM()`, `COUNT()`, etc). So that `SELECT task` should probably be changed to `SELECT DATE(datetask) AS date_of_task`.
- It's not good to use `BETWEEN .. AND ..` for ranges of datetime and timestamp columns. The condition `WHERE datetask BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND '2015-10-31'` will seemingly gather all rows of this October. Except that almost all the rows of the 31st of October will escape!

  The reason is that the condition is equivalent to `WHERE datetask BETWEEN '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-31 00:00:00'` and all rows with datetime values that are not in midnight exactly (`00:00:00`) will fail the condition and will not be counted in the query.

  Even if you use something like `WHERE datetask BETWEEN '2015-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-10-31 23:59:59'`, you have a few drawbacks: It's more complicated to write. It will work but only if the precision of the dtateime/timestamp is 1 second. If the column has millisecond or microsecond precision (this is allowed in 5.6+ versions), you'll have to change the condition to have `... AND '2015-10-31 23:59:59.999999'`.

  My suggestion is to use the `WHERE column >=? AND column < (? + INTERVAL 1 DAY)` pattern. It's guaranteed to work on all `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` types of arbitrary precision.

Now for the multiple counts, there are several methods. Perhaps the easiest to write is:

```
SELECT DATE(datetask) AS date_of_task,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 END) AS status_1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 END) AS status_2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN 1 END) AS status_3
FROM tasks 
WHERE datetask >= ? AND datetask < (? + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  AND taskstatus = ?  
GROUP BY DATE(datetask) 
ORDER BY date_of_task ASC ;
```

which  can be simplified a bit, to:

```
SELECT DATE(datetask) AS date_of_task,
       SUM(status = 1) AS status_1,
       SUM(status = 2) AS status_2,
       SUM(status = 3) AS status_3
FROM tasks 
WHERE datetask >= ? AND datetask < (? + INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  AND taskstatus = ?  
GROUP BY DATE(datetask) ASC ;    -- combine GROUP BY and ORDER BY
```

Comment: Can you explain why there is a need for INTERVAL 1 Day in the datetask < ?

Comment: Edited the answer with some more details.

Comment: Got also a quite "stupid question" is it possible to display 0 in the other days? So if we got 2015-11-01 has no status - could it be written 0?

Comment: What does it write now? `COUNT()` or `SUM()` should display 0 in that case. Or you mean the case when a date has no related rows at all?

Comment: It works all ok but I want as you said | the case when a date has no related rows at all?|

Comment: That requires a table of all dates.  Then `LEFT JOIN` from that table to the rest of the query.